# Is there a better way to do this i have a working code but i think it could be optimized?

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a better way to achieve this ? Basically I have a list that may contain anagrams. I need to return a list with the anagrams and if there are more than one occurence of that anagram I need only the first occurence. I can achieve the result using above code but I think this could be optimized for sure. Appreciate any input.

```
#Input
#words = ['8', 'bat', 'rats', 'srat', 'rtas', 'god', 'dog', 'cat', 'arts', 'star']

#Ouput
#['god', 'rats']
```

```
from itertools import permutations

final_list = []
unique_list = []

words = ['bat', 'rats', 'srat', 'rtas', 'god', 'dog', 'cat', 'arts', 'star']


sort_words = {}
for word in words:
    sort_words[word] = ''.join(sorted(word))

#print(sort_words)
anagrams = []
for i in range(len(words)):
    ana = [words[i]]
    for j in range(i + 1, len(words)):
        if sort_words[words[i]] == sort_words[words[j]]:
            ana.append(words[j])
    if len(ana) != 1:
        anagrams.append(ana)

print(anagrams)

for sublist in anagrams:
    for item in sublist:
        final_list.append(item)

print(final_list)

res = []
anag = set()
for x in final_list:
    if x in anag:
        continue
    res.append(x)
    for per in permutations(x):
        anag.add(''.join(per))
res = sorted(res)

print(res)
```

Comment: If the code is complete and works, it should be on Code Review instead. This site is primarily for fixing broken code.

Comment: link: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Please delete this now that you've posted it over there.